# image not appearing on secondary tile

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

Hi i'm trying to resize an image to show it in a secondary tile.My code works fine  but i don't know what i'm doing wrong because when the image is bigger than 1000*1000   the image is not shown in the secondary tile
this is my code  that i use to resize

```
//restablecemos el nuevo tamañao 100*100
            using (var sourceStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(sourceStream);
                BitmapTransform transform = new BitmapTransform() { ScaledHeight =100, ScaledWidth= 100 };
                PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(
                BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8,
                BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
                transform,
                ExifOrientationMode.RespectExifOrientation,
                ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage);

                using (var destinationStream = await localfile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                {
                    BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, destinationStream);
                    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied, 100,100,96, 96, pixelData.DetachPixelData());
                    await encoder.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
```

and this is my code that i use to pin and show the secondary tile

```
  private async void btnpin(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //mantenmos abierta el appbar
        this.miappbar.IsSticky = true;

        //obtenemos la imagen del .json y la mostramos en  la nota
        Uri smalllogo = new Uri(pequeniaImagen);

        //creamos el secondary tile
        SecondaryTile secondary = new SecondaryTile(logoSecondaryTileld, String.Format("{0} {1:d}",pageTitle.Text,Convert.ToDateTime(tvFecha.Text)),pageTitle.Text,logoSecondaryTileld, TileOptions.ShowNameOnLogo,smalllogo);
        secondary.DisplayName =pageTitle.Text;//nombre de la nota
        //obtenemos el color de fondo del secondary tile
        SolidColorBrush brush= Editor.returnColorfromString(Mcolor);
        secondary.BackgroundColor = brush.Color;
        //color del texto
        secondary.ForegroundText = ForegroundText.Dark;


        bool isPinned = await secondary.RequestCreateForSelectionAsync(detalles.GetElementRect((FrameworkElement)sender), Windows.UI.Popups.Placement.Below);
        //el usuario pinieo la nota
        if (isPinned)
        {
            //ocultamos el btn pin
            btnpin.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            //mostramos el btn unpin
            btnunpin.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            this.firstbord.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        }

        this.miappbar.IsSticky = false;

    }
```

does anybody knows the reason of this error?

i hope you can help me

thanks

Comment: you mention 1000x1000 is that precise?   There is a [limit of 1024x1024 or 200KB total](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781198.aspx)

Comment: thank you  i saved my images as .gif and now it works :)